# Xamarin.ios Segue Animation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a storyboard that at some point moves from one view to another, but the animations that area available to the segway are Cover Vertically, Flip Horizontally, Cross dissolve and partial curl. I need to have a "Slide to the right" animation. How can I add this?

Also, I'm able to use this kind of animations if the segue is Modal type, which as I understand is a view being drawn over the other view. I would like to "Push", as I understand pushing discards the past view.

Comment: Xamarin's `ios-samples`(https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples) contains that exact type of `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` in the `CustomTransitions` solution (along with others)

Comment: Thank you SushiHangover!